# Create column, separated by "," as a numeric output

Tags: r, strsplit

I am trying to present data that is currently in rows as `"XXX-XX-0001, YY-YY-0001"` into a new column, outlining the number within each row [2]

I have managed to mutate a new column, however it is a character output `chr [2]`, i need this to be just 2.

```
{r}
bill <- bill %>%
mutate(NO_IA = strsplit(as.character(IA_YES), ","))
```

When I try to use as `.numeric`, It doesn't like that my input is "," - also if I try to double up it reject its to ( `as.numeric` & `as.character` in same line)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some clarification, here is a better answer:

## data (fromt the comment)

```
string <- scan(text = "
AAA-GB-0001 
BBB-ES-0005,ADD-GB-0001 
BSC-ES-0005,HQQ-GB-0001,REE-GB-0001 
BDD-GB-0001,BSC-ES-0005,HQQ-GB-0001,UZZ-DE-0001 
BDD-GB-0001,UEE-DE-0001 
BDD-GB-0001,BRE-EE-0005,CTT-DE-0002,LZZ-DE-0011,UZZ-DE-0001", 
               what = character(), sep = "\n")

library(dplyr)
bill <- tibble(IA_YES = string)
```

Next time it would make sense to provide some example data. For example by using `dput()` (in this case copy the result from `dput(bill)`.

## solution

Note that the `strsplit` command in your code creates a list. The list is stored in the newly created column and can be used as any other list in `R`. We can use the `purrr` package to operate on lists, which provides better versions of `R`'s *apply functions:

```
bill %>%
  mutate(NO_IA = strsplit(as.character(IA_YES), ",")) %>% 
  mutate(length = map_int(NO_IA, length))
#> # A tibble: 6 x 3
#>   IA_YES                                                    NO_IA    length
#>   <chr>                                                     <list>    <int>
#> 1 "AAA-GB-0001 "                                            <chr [1~      1
#> 2 "BBB-ES-0005,ADD-GB-0001 "                                <chr [2~      2
#> 3 "BSC-ES-0005,HQQ-GB-0001,REE-GB-0001 "                    <chr [3~      3
#> 4 "BDD-GB-0001,BSC-ES-0005,HQQ-GB-0001,UZZ-DE-0001 "        <chr [4~      4
#> 5 "BDD-GB-0001,UEE-DE-0001 "                                <chr [2~      2
#> 6 BDD-GB-0001,BRE-EE-0005,CTT-DE-0002,LZZ-DE-0011,UZZ-DE-0~ <chr [5~      5
```

A short explanation of `map_int(NO_IA, length)`: `map` functions all work in the same way. You provide a list or a vector that can be transformed to a list and apply a function to it. In this case we measure the `length()` of each entry in the list. An alternative way to write it would be `map_int(NO_IA, function(x) length(x))`. The advantage of `purrr` compared to the `apply` functions is that you can control the output better. `map_int` will return an integer, `map_chr`, for example, returns a character object.

## Old answer

You can just replace the comma with a dot before converting it:

```
library(dplyr)df <- tibble(num = c("12,3", "10.7"))
df %>% 
  mutate(num = as.numeric(sub(",", ".", num, fixed = TRUE)))
#> # A tibble: 2 x 1
#>     num
#>   <dbl>
#> 1  12.3
#> 2  10.7
```

More "tidy" version:

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- tibble(num = c("12,3", "10.7"))
df %>% 
  mutate(num = str_replace(num, fixed(","), ".") %>%  
           as.numeric())
#> # A tibble: 2 x 1
#>     num
#>   <dbl>
#> 1  12.3
#> 2  10.7
```

Comment: How do i direct this as my column for the replace. currently you have strings 12,3 , 10.7.

Comment: I don't understand this sentence. Maybe you include some data in your question, so it is easier to help you. Currently, what I understood is that you have a character column that you need to convert to numeric.

Comment: IA_YES
1.AAA-GB-0001
2. BBB-ES-0005,ADD-GB-0001
3. BSC-ES-0005,HQQ-GB-0001,REE-GB-0001
4 .BDD-GB-0001,BSC-ES-0005,HQQ-GB-0001,UZZ-DE-0001
5. BDD-GB-0001,UEE-DE-0001
6. BDD-GB-0001,BRE-EE-0005,CTT-DE-0002,LZZ-DE-0011,UZZ-DE-0001

I need to be able to count in each numbered row, the number of strings separated by a comma. apologies for the confusion

Comment: I think I understood now what you need. Take a look.

Comment: Hi JBG - thanks this works, also i was able to resolve another way. 
```
bill <- bill %>%
  mutate(NO_IA = str_count(IA_YES, ",")+1)
```

just needed to add another comma count on the end of each to get the same answer (i.e 1 would not have a comma).

thank you for your help!

Comment: Great! I was thinking about `str_count` as well but I thought you needed the list column as well, at which point it makes sense to count how long the list elements actually are.